# Does eating a cookie created using coffee beans has the same effect as drinking coffee?

Tags: caffeine, beans

There are some cookie recipes using coffee beans. I've never tried any of them. But I am curious, if eating a cookie has the same effect as drinking coffee?

Or is all of the caffeine lost during the baking?

Comment: The heat of baking will not have any effect on the caffeine, which is an extremely stable organic molecule.  See this [previous Answer](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/277/34) for related information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because there is no fluid in the cookie.  Eating a coffee cookie will have the same effect as eating a roasted coffee bean.

Virtually no caffeine will be lost during baking, unless you bake hot enough to burn the cookies.  Caffeine's melting point is 460F (237 °C).  That is well above what your cookie will reach internally while in the oven.