# Moka vs. pour-over oil extraction efficiency

Tags: moka, pour-over

What are the differences in the coffee made from a moka pot vs. a pour-over? Does one extract more of the beans' oil than another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mokas extract oils ([fatty acids](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fatty%20acid)) better than pour-over or filter coffee methods, which are the poorest. French presses do the best at fatty acid, presumably due to the grains being submersed so water-oil separation has more time to occur.

According to

- Alexia N. Gloess et al., “[Comparison of Nine Common Coffee Extraction Methods: Instrumental and Sensory Analysis](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00217-013-1917-x),” *European Food Research and Technology* **236**, no. 4 (April 1, 2013): 607–27, DOI: [10.1007/s00217-013-1917-x](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00217-013-1917-x), §9 Extraction Efficiency, p. 618,

a French press (Bo) by far has the best "Fatty Acids per g R&G" extraction efficiency, with the Bialetti moka pot coming in a distant second place {plot (b) below}:

Fatty acid content per gram of roasted and ground coffee (R&G) prepared according to the different extraction methods:

[image: Content per gram of ground coffee (R&G) prepared according to the different extraction methods]

Key:

- Espresso from semi-automatic machine—(DE)
- Lungo from semi-automatic machine—(DL)
- Espresso from fully automatic machine—(SE)
- Lungo from fully automatic machine—(SL)
- Espresso—Nespresso (NE)
- Espresso—Bialetti (Bia)
- Lungo—French Press (Bo)
- Lungo—Karlsbader Kanne (KK)
- Lungo—Filter Coffee (F)

Comment: Answers should be written in your own words, text from other sources should *support* your answer, not make up the majority of the answer. Copied text must be both attributed *and marked* as such. Linking to your own space without denoting it as such is undisclosed affiliation and not permitted either (and frankly totally unnecessary in this case).

Comment: See [How to reference material written by others](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) (“Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.”) and [this Meta Q/A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160078/310311) (“Remember, you still have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text, even when attributed, is not your work either. Use quotes sparingly, to support your own words.”)

Comment: How do fatty acids relate to oil? Are fatty acids the same as oil? Are all fatty acids in the bean oily? Are all oils in coffee beans fatty acids? And how does the pour over figure into this? It seems filter coffee has no fatty oil extraction. Is that because they only used a paper filter? Though this source seems to be relevant, I'd reiterate Stephie's comment that you have to actually answer the question.

Comment: I understand that the source you're citing only published the figures in bulk, but in your answer it's quite confusing as it seems you're only using that one plot. Perhaps removing the picture and citing the relevant numbers in a table would be easier?

Answer (score 3):

Pourover methods tend to use a paper filter which prevents oils from flowing into the coffee. Pourover is also brewed at a low pressure and a higher coffee to water ratio, giving the coffee a gentler, tealike taste. Moka pots are closer to espresso in terms of intensity and pressure, and does have more body and a richer flavour. I personally prefer pourover coffee but everyone has their own tastes.